# How to get notified when a new list or library has been created?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

We need to react to new document libraries and/or lists being created in SharePoint sites. Is there a way to get notified when this happens?

[Graph change notifications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) currently only seem to exist for *items within* a document library.

Which options do we have to get notified of new list and libraries? Any clever workarounds like listening for some other change connected to new libs and lists? So far I did not came up with anything.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a remote event receiver using `SPRemoteEventType.ListAdded` and implement your logic there.

This is a web-scoped feature so you'd have to deploy this to every site you want to track.

This is the only way I'm aware of to do this.

Comment: Good info. Do I have to build a provider-hosted add-in around it or can I just use CSOM to register it?

Comment: you can register it in csom. Here's how I would do it today: https://spblog.net/post/2021/09/14/how-to-use-remote-event-receivers-with-net-core-or-net-5-and-pnp-framework

Comment: Wow this is timing - written a week ago. Thanks, this seems to be the way.